# unary operator expected with integerrs and arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, unix

So I wrote the following code :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "for loop"

names=("fulmetall" "alphonse" "flame alchemesit" "king bradely" "hoenheim")

a=0
while [ $a -lt 5 ];
do
        echo ${names[$a]}
        a=`expr a + 1`
done
```

And get the following Error, And I have no idea why it didn't work.
The first name is printed, and the others are not.

```
for loop
fulmetall
expr: non-integer argument
./for_loop.sh: line 8: [: -lt: unary operator expected
```

Comment: Use `expr $a...` instead of just `a` or save yourself some future trouble and use arithmetic expansion: `((a++))` or `a=$((a+1))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "for loop"

names=("fulmetall" "alphonse" "flame alchemesit" "king bradely" "hoenheim")

a=0
while [ $a -lt 5 ];
do
    echo ${names[$a]}
    a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```